# D-brane, and SUSY charges

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics, supersymmetry, branes

The following results summarize the relation between orientifold and D-brane, and SUSY charge
$$
\begin{array}{l||c|c|c|c|c|c}\text{orientifold} &\text{O4} & \text{O3} & \text{O2} &\text{O1} & \text{O0} \\
\text{D-brane involved} & \text{D2} &\text{D3} & \text{D4}  &\text{D5} & \text{D6}\\
\text{SUSY on the D-brane} &  \mathcal{N} =8  &  \mathcal{N} = 4  &  \mathcal{N} = 2  &  \mathcal{N} =(1,1)  &  \mathcal{N} = 1 \\
\text{dimensons} &   d=3   &   d=4   &   d=5   &   d=6   &   d=7   
\end{array}
$$
It looks that the spacetime dimensions correspond to $d=3$,  $d=4$,   $d=5$,  $d=6$, and  $d=7$.

Is it known how the SUSY charge $\mathcal{N}$ are related to the spacetime dimensions $d$?

But it seems that the relation does not directly relate to the familiar result between spacetime dimensions $d$ and SUSY charge $\mathcal{N}$? See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/587879/42982